# Mac Terminal lowercase "a" stopped working. Why?

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

Whenever I type "a" in Terminal, I get a beep, and no output.  If in uppercase, "A" types fine.  This computer (new mac mini) is only a few days old, but I've done a few things that may have caused this behavior:

1) Installed DoubleCommand.  Disabling all options in DoubleCommand doesn't help

2) Change some of the keyboard shortcuts in Terminal (specifically: Home, PgUp, PgDn, End, shift+PgUp, shift+PgDn).  Switching to a different theme (where my keyboard shortcut changes don't exist) does not help.

What I haven't tried:

<strike>1) restart</strike> (**Update2: tried, didn't help**)

<strike>2) uninstalling DoubleCommand</strike>  (**Update 2: tried, didn't help**)

**Update:**
lowercase "a" works in Vim, but just not at command prompt

Comment: Any changes to your `.inputrc`, `.bash_profile`? Do you run `screen` or `tmux`? Also, seriously? You take the time to post and explain your issue and expect others to answer, but don't restart your machine? This is number 1 troubleshooting advice for a reason.

Comment: @Daniel: I thought I cleared out my .bash_profile and .inputrc, but did so again to be sure, and presto, this fixed my issue!  Much thanks.. Can I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: You can't unless he reposts it as an answer.

Comment: Now you can :-) I don't like posting troubleshooting suggestions as questions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if there's anything odd in your `.inputrc` or `.bash_profile`. Best to move them to a different folder temporarily and see if the problem goes away.